# How to remove event handler codes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I try to delete those empty handlers the form gets broken. How can I remove those annoying codes from my program without affecting form?

[image]

Comment: Could you add this code here as a snippet, not a screenshot?

Answer (score 5):

When you delete the `btnOrder_Click` you should also delete the following line in `yourForm.Designer.cs`:

```
this.btnOrder.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnOrder_Click);
```

To find this line after you removed the `btnOrder_Click` rebuild your project and then in the **Error List** window double click on error which says:

> 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'btnOrder_Click' and no extension method 'btnOrder_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

By double clicking on this error you will redirect to that line and after deleting that line your form returns back.

Comment: This technique is called "Leaning on the compiler" and I'm a fan of it :) +1

Comment: Also from Properties window: `events tab > right click on event > reset`

Comment: This is why it is annoing to hear people say: NEVER EDIT THE DESIGNER FILE MANUALLY! If you have deleted the event handler in the .cs file, you have to manually delete the rest in the designer file.