# How to fix Visual Studio designer error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

A project I'm making at the moment keeps getting errors from the Designer, saying that a designer line of code doesn't contain a definition.

I am coding this in C#.

> Error    CS1061  'Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Form1_Load'
>   and no extension method 'Form1_Load' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

```
// 
// Form1
// 
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(405, 327);
this.Controls.Add(this.bunifuFlatButton2);
this.Controls.Add(this.bunifuFlatButton1);
this.Controls.Add(this.bunifuMaterialTextbox2);
this.Controls.Add(this.bunifuMaterialTextbox1);
this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
this.Name = "Form1";                        
this.Text = "Form1";                      ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load); ← Error here
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
this.ResumeLayout(false);
this.PerformLayout();
```

[Here is the alert it's giving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yf66u.png)

If you want any more code from the designer or you want me to add code from my project, just comment down bellow.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/35981547/2946329

Comment: I don't understand it, could you maybe explain? @S.Akbari

Comment: It looks like you deleted the event handling method without doing so via the designer which won't automatically remove the event subscription. Add the method `Form_Load` back in manually or delete the offending line and add it back (if necessary) using the designer once you've done that first.

Answer (score 0):

just comment this line out

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load); ← Error here
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! @nasser fet

Comment: @Zualux, you should re-add the `Form1_Load` event to your code, or delete that line. Commenting out the designer code is bad practice as it is autogenerated for you as you make edits in the designer.

Comment: Okay, will definetly look at that. @sillyhairboy

Comment: thank you @sillyhairboy , thank you Zualux